# No llega la variable por POST al PHP mediante AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente script el cual envia una variable tomada de un input, hace una consulta y devuelve los campos de mencionada consulta para luego realizar mas acciones, aqui el AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#boton_comprobar_producto").click(function ()
  {
//tomo el texto del input
    var codigo_producto=document.getElementById("input_codigo_producto").value;

$.ajax({
      data: codigo_producto,
      url: "../PHP/consultar_datos_producto.php",
// he puesto y quitado esto de cache y no solucionó nada
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      beforeSend: function()
      {
        $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html("buscando producto...");
        //ANTES ENVIAR EL DATO COMPRUEBO QUE SI LO ESTA TOMANDO, HASTA AQUI TODO VA BIEN YA QUE ME ALERTA LO QUE ESCRIBO EN EL INPUT
        alert(codigo_producto);
      },
      success: function(respuesta)
      {
        //COMPRUEBO SI NO HAY RESULTADOS
        if(respuesta=="producto no encontrado")
        {   
          $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html("Producto no encontrado");
        }
        else
        {
          //mostrar la descripcion del producto
          alert(respuesta[0]);

          //mostrar el costo del producto
          alert(respuesta[1]);

          //borrar contenido del div que decia "buscando producto..." ya que si lo encontró
          $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html("");
        }
      },
      error : function()
      {
        alert('Hubo un error');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

AQUI EL consultar_datos_producto.php

```
<?php
require('conectar.php');
//SE SUPONE QUE AQUI RECIBO LA VARIABLE
$codigo_producto=$_POST['codigo_producto'];

//echo para probar que si se este recibiendo el dato, no muestra absolutamente nada en consola del explorador, ni siquiera un null o algo por el estilo lo cual se me hace raro
echo $codigo_producto;

//compruebo algun error en la consulta
if (!mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM productos WHERE codigo ='$codigo_producto'"))
{
  echo("Error de MySQL: " . mysqli_error($conexion));
}

//realizo consulta, si aqui en vez de colocar codigo='$codigo_producto' uso codigo='ABC888' el cual yo se que existe, en ese caso funciona todo de maravilla

$result = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM productos WHERE codigo ='$codigo_producto'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  //armo un array con los resultados
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
        //posicion 0 la descripcion del producto
        $output[] = $row["descripcion"];
        //posicion 1 el costo del producto
        $output[] = $row["costo"];
   }
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
     $output='producto no encontrado';
}

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

La conclusion a la que llego es que no me esta enviando el dato al servidor por POST por que como lo dije antes, si cambio la variable por un codigo de producto que se que existe, todo funciona de maravilla. O es eso o simplemente algo tengo mal en el php

alguna idea?

Comment: y podes comprobar si aca lo encuentra? var codigo_producto=document.getElementById("input_codigo_producto").value;

Comment: @gbianchi si ya que en beforeSend: function() hago un alert tal como describo ahi y me alerta el valor que digito en el input

Comment: En el caso de que sea un fallo, en el ajax error:function() haz error:function(output) y haces un console log del mismo para ver que es.

Answer (score 0):

En el javascript estas indicando que envías los datos en formato json. PHP no realiza el parsing automaticamente cuanto los datos vienen en ese formato.
Puedes hacerlo manualmente así:

```
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: En el caso de mi proyecto como iria exactamente esa linea? que deberia modificarle? ademas, iria antes de $codigo_producto = $_POST['codigo_producto']; para parsar primero?

Answer (score 0):

Debes realizar las siguientes correcciones en JavaScript. Lo que se describe a continuación es lo que debes seguir corregir tu código JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#boton_comprobar_producto").click(function () {
    // Si estás utilizando jQuery, se recomienda 
    // obtener el valor de la siguiente manera:
    var codigo_producto = $("#input_codigo_producto").val();

    // Se recomienda crear un objeto para pasar los parámetros
    // al archivo «consultar_datos_producto.php»
    var parametros = {
      "codigo_producto": codigo_producto
    }

    $.ajax({
      data: parametros,
      url: "../PHP/consultar_datos_producto.php",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",

      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html("Buscando producto...");
      },

      success: function(content, status) {
        // Se recomienda realizar las comprobaciones así:
        if (status == "success") {
          $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html(content);
        }

      },

      error : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        // Debe mostrar el siguiente resultado si se presenta
        // un error en el archivo consultar_datos_producto.php
        $('#div_estado_busqueda_producto').html(jqXHR.responseText);
      }
    });

  });
});
```

---

En cuanto al archivo «**consultar_datos_producto.php**», te recomiendo inicializar la variable $output si no lo has hecho en otro archivo, es decir:

```
$output = "";
```

Además, debes colocarle '@' para que no se muestre ningún error en caso de no haberse enviado la petición mediante el método POST. Se recomienda utilizarlo en producción el '@'. Por ejemplo:

```
$codigo_producto = @$_POST['codigo_producto'];
```

Por otro lado, elimina:

```
echo $codigo_producto; // De lo contrario, se producirá un error en tu proyecto.
```

Comment: Es una terrible idea usar @ para esconder los errores, eso no ayuda en nada para atender eventuales fallos

Comment: De hecho, recomendé su uso en producción, tal y como lo indiqué en el comentario anterior, ya que el producto final no debe mostrar errores a los usuarios finales. En tiempo de desarrollo no se utiliza el '@' para visualizar los errores.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. el problema es que la `@`  no trata el error, como dice @shadow, lo esconde, lo apropiado seria usar [isset()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) o [empty()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) para no ir arrastrando malos hábitos, con un operador ternario quedaría: `$codigo_producto = $isset($_POST['codigo_producto'])?$_POST['codigo_producto']:null`

Comment: Está bien la observación y entiendo tu punto:
`$codigo_producto = $isset($_POST['codigo_producto'])?$_POST['codigo_producto']:null`, pero la idea era orientar para darle solución a un problema planteado.